# Showing UIButton on top of cordova webview

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm building a cordova plugin which will show a native iOS button on top of the current cordova view when I click a button. I'm getting an error about `Invariant Violation, framesToPop: 1` in the xcode emulator for ios. I'm not sure what is going wrong with my code:

```
- (void)getButton:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{

    // define error variable
    NSString *error = nil;

    // create array to hold args
    NSArray* args = command.arguments;

    // create variable to hold response
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult;

    // map command inputs
    NSString* callbackUrl = [args objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* useCaseId = [args objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString* clientSdkId = [args objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString* scenarioId = [args objectAtIndex:3];

    if ([callbackUrl length] == 0) {
        error = @"missing callbackUrl";
    }

    if ([useCaseId length] == 0) {
        error = @"missing useCaseId";
    }

    if ([clientSdkId length] == 0) {
        error = @"missing clientSdkId";
    }

    if ([scenarioId length] == 0) {
        error = @"missing clientSdkId";
    }

    if ([error length] > 0) {
        pluginResult = [
            CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"Missing an input"
        ];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [
            CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"it works"
        ];
    }

    //[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    UIViewController *myController = [UIViewController init];
    
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [myButton setTitle:@"My button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];

    [myController.view addSubview:myButton];
    
    [self.webView.superview insertSubview:myController.view aboveSubview:self.webView];
    
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK] callbackId:command.callbackId];

}

@end
```

I would expect this button to be shown on the screen? From what I understand of the logic I am inserting another view on top of the cordova view controllers webview. I am new to developing plugins for cordova so I'm not sure if I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `@synthesize` to the top of this file